# Switching X and Y Coordinates in Maze Solving Algorithm Using Stack in Python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, maze

I'm trying to get my head around a simple maze solving algorithm using a stack in Python 3.

I've found some code and added some output to track what's going on, but the person who wrote the code used x,y coordinates (in that order) for a 2d array. As I understand, it should use y, x instead (for row then column). I'm having enough trouble following the algorithm without having to mentally switch x and y to understand what is happening.

I'm pretty sure it's a tiny change, but could someone please suggest a modification which would make the code display and trace the coordinates correctly? I'm not concerned whether the y-axis increases in an upward or downward direction.

My tiny maze is represented as below:

```
 ***
  **
* **
* G*
```

and the code is as follows:

```
# This program traverses a maze using a stack.

from sq import Stack              # import a Stack type from sq.py

MAZE_SIZE = 4                    # define the size of the maze

def PrintMaze(maze):              # an auxilliary function that prints a maze
    for row in range(MAZE_SIZE):
        print(maze[row], end='')
    print()

def InBounds(xxx_todo_changeme):              # an auxillary function that determines if (x,y) is on the maze
    (x,y) = xxx_todo_changeme
    return (0 <= x < MAZE_SIZE) and (0 <= y < MAZE_SIZE)

def Maze(maze, start):          # traverse 'maze' from starting coordinates 'start'
    s = Stack()                  # create a new Stack named s
    s.push(start);               # push the start coordinates onto s
    while not s.isEmpty():       # loop while s is not empty
        print(s.list)
        input("press Enter to continue ")
        (x, y) = s.pop()          # pop a coordinate off s into the tuple (x,y)
        print('Trying position ({}, {})'.format(x,y))
        if InBounds((x,y)):         # if (x,y) is on the maze then
            if maze[x][y] == 'G':    # if (x,y) is the goal then
                s.empty()             # empty the stack because we're done
            elif maze[x][y] == ' ':  # else if (x,y) is an undiscovered coordinate
                print('filling ({}, {})'.format(x,y))
                maze[x] = maze[x][:y] + 'D' + maze[x][y+1:]  # mark (x,y) discovered with 'D'
                PrintMaze(maze);      # print the maze to show progress so far
                s.push((x+1, y))      # push right neighbor onto stack s
                s.push((x, y+1))      # push lower neighbor onto stack s
                s.push((x-1, y))      # push left neighbor onto stack s
                s.push((x, y-1))      # push upper neighbor onto stack s
        else:
            print('Out of bounds.')

# The following can be used to create a maze and traverse it:

import sys
maze = open('maze2.dat', 'r')     # open the file 'maze.dat' for reading
maze = maze.readlines();         # read the file into maze
Maze(maze, (0,0))                 # traverse the maze starting at (0,0)
```

Answer (score 2):

After the line

```
input("press Enter to continue ")
```

You can simply enter:

```
(y, x) = s.pop()
```

Which flips the coordinates for the whole code

I recently worked on a Maze Solver too... Here's a sample maze and printing function from my code:

```
maze=[[ 0 ,0,1,1,0,'S'],
      [ 0 ,0,0,0,1, 0 ],
      ['F',1,0,0,0, 0 ],
      [ 0 ,0,0,0,1, 0 ],
      [ 0 ,1,0,0,0, 0 ]]
## 0 represents empty space, 1 represents a wall
def printmaze(maze):
    for i in maze:
        for j in i:
            print('X' if j==1 else (' ' if j==0 else j),end='')
        print()
```

Also in your code:

```
def PrintMaze(maze):              # an auxilliary function that prints a maze
    for row in range(MAZE_SIZE):
        print(maze[row], end='')
    print()
```

is the same as:

```
def PrintMaze(maze):
    for row in maze:
        print(row)
```

In order to invert the printing you should do:

```
for col in range(MAZE_SIZE):
    for row in maze:
        print(row[col],end='')
    print()
```

Comment: That did occur to me but the output didn't make sense. I've switched the x and y in the other print statements too and it seems to work.

Comment: Could you share your code's output in the above question?